# TLS server: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:2081 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Certificate Expired

Tags: ssl, openssl, rabbitmq, ssl-certificate

I'm seeing this error in my logs when trying to start my API: TLS server: In state certify at ssl_handshake.erl:2081 generated SERVER ALERT: Fatal - Certificate Expired

The root CA in the Trusted Root Certification and this was a new certificate given to me. What causes this issue with Rabbit MQ? How can I fix this?

Comment: It may be new to you but it has expired, or another one in the chain has, or you haven't installed it properly.